# When are file objects passed directly as argument to another function garbage collected?

Tags: python, file, garbage-collection, corruption

If I'm going to pass an `open(filename)` object directly as argument to another method, say `json.load()`, in this way:

```
data = json.load(open("filename.json"))
```

can I be sure that the open stream is *garbage-collected*, thus closed, as soon as `json.load()` finishes its execution, or I'm going to face corruption issues very soon?

I know the best practice would be `with open(filename) as f:` syntax, but what if I insisted for a one-liner solution?

Comment: If you're so insistent on a one-liner, you can just shove the whole `with` into one line: `with open(filename) as f: data = json.load(f)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's actually a good workaround! I've read somewhere that one-liner indentations are bad for PEP but i can ignore it in this case. Still it's interesting to know what happens to that file object in memory.

Comment: @MaxShouman no, that's an *absurd* workaround, because it's not working around anything except an irrational need to make something a one-liner.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it was very interesting to read and it's a general overview of a broad problem, but it doesn't focus on my specific case, i.e. the file is implicitly assigned to a function local var; when the function is done with its task theorically the name is removed and being the only one reference to the object, it should be removed (according to CPython, but portability is not a problem in my case).

Comment: In any case, in Python, objects are free for garbage collection when their reference count reaches zero. As long as the function you are using is free of side-effects that might silently create a reference, e.g. appending the object to some list in the global scope, then as soon as the function returns, local references cease to exist and the object is no-longer referenced anywhere, and it is free for garbage collection

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it might be irrational, but what is the problem with preferring more concise solutions if they don't bring further problems?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the explanation btw, that's exactly what I needed to know!