# Trouble with making a login function in python

Tags: python, append, login-page

Hello I am a student and I have been researching on here for way too long to find answers to how to make this login page actually work. All the pages I have found have made them in different ways that don't work for me. Can anyone off this code push me on the right track to create this. I have got my signup page to work though.

```
def signup():
    
    users = open("login_signup.txt","a")
    user = []
    username = input("What do you want your username to be?: ")
    password = input("What do you want your password to be?: ")
    user.append(username)
    user.append(password)
    users.write(username + "," + password)
    users.write("\n")

    print("You have successfully signed up")


def login():
    
    with open("login_signup.txt","r") as users:
        
        usersusername = input("What is your username?: ")
        userspassword = input("What is your password?: ")
```

Btw the format off the text in the file is: username,password

Then it goes to a new line after the next person wants to create an account.

Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: You have opened the file so far. Read a line in that file. Split that line by a comma. Index and store [0] as the username and [1] as the password. Stored usr & pwd to the newly inputed usr & pwd.

Comment: I'm getting lost up to the index and store bit how do you do that?

Comment: If you have text such as `"a,b"` and preform `split(',')` on this you will have a list. `['a','b']`. In your case if you index this new list as `text[0]` you will get the username. Then if you index this list as `text[1]` you will get the password.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense I will try and see what I can do. Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check text file for usernames and passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738966/how-to-check-text-file-for-usernames-and-passwords)

Comment: You don't even need to index anything, just read the file line by line and check if the line matches what user entered, e.g. `for line in users: if line.strip() == f'{usersusername},{userspassword}': ...`

Comment: def login():
    # Should read text file and check if the password and username are correct

    with open("login_signup.txt","r") as users:
        
        usersusername = input("What is your username?: ")
        userspassword = input("What is your password?: ")

        for line in users: 
            if line.strip() == f'{usersusername},{userspassword}':
                print("You have successfully signed in!")
            else:
                print("Your credentials were incorrect please try again!")
                login()

Is this good?

Comment: I know this isn’t the main thrust of your question, but this is a very bad way to manage passwords. There is no reason to ever store a password in plaintext, and there are many libraries and services you can use that have secure and flexible user authentication.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson its just for a school project thing and it is allowed to be in a text file and for other aspects in my project I need to use this logic. And the code above doesn't work.

Comment: I just saw your comment now thanks @DarrylG I am currently looking at it now

Comment: In the linked solution just change split from splitting on space (the default) to splitting on comma i.e. `login_info = line.split(',')`

Comment: It still isn't working, I really don't know what is going on @DarrylG

Comment: @RmT--does my answer work for you?  Is it understandable?

Comment: @DarryIG I can’t get it to work for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're still having problems here's a modification of your code that works.

```
def signup():
    
    with open("login_signup.txt","a") as users: # context manager is preferred over pure open/close
        #user = []                              # not used so remove
        username = input("What do you want your username to be?: ")
        password = input("What do you want your password to be?: ")
        #user.append(username)                  # not used so remove
        #user.append(password)                  # not used so remove
        users.write(username + "," + password)
        users.write("\n")

        print("You have successfully signed up")


def login():
    
    usersname = input("What is your username?: ")
    userspassword = input("What is your password?: ")
  
    with open("login_signup.txt", "r") as users:

        for line in users:                              # iterating over login file a line at a time
            login_info = line.rstrip().split(',')       # rstrip() removes the '\n' at end of string
                                                        # split(',' split string on comma 
            if usersname == login_info[0] and userspassword == login_info[1]:
                print("Correct credentials!")
                return True
        
    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    return False
```

**Exmaple Run**

```
sigup()
# Out:
#     What do you want your username to be?: john
#     What do you want your password to be?: paul
#     You have successfully signed up


login()
# Out:
#    What is your username?: john
#    What is your password?: paul
#    Correct credentials!
#    True
```

Comment: @DarryIG This works thank you so much for all your help over the past day!