ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error while trying to import a dataset with pandas
I am trying just to read a dataset which is in a drive in csv format, but I keep getting the error:
"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 1287"
This is my code, is really basic:
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rDc9LKvnVjWyldo6N3UN0D4nMAxId47L/view?usp=drive_link'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df.head())

It shows that in the line of reading the url is where I have the problem.
I wanted to see the first rows of the dataset.

Does this answer your question? Python read_csv - ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Welcome to SO! You probably should specify read_csv arguments such as header and/or separator. See [ask] to [edit] your question into one we may answer. For instance, post a representative sample as text. Reading the pandas read_csv docs, or searching SO for the multiple occurrences of this question, should also help.

"see the first rows of the dataset."? Do you mean to print a few lines? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1904394/12846804

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe first open this url in web browser using private mode and see what you get - maybe you get HTML with error message instead of CSV data.

Maybe your document in drive is in private, check the share configuration.
